# What is the purpose of this PCB next to air pressure switch? Do I need it?

Tags: humidifier

I recently noticed the whole house humidifier (installed by the previous owner) stopped working (Honeywell 280A).  Filter dry, no flow, no click from the solonoid valve.

I did some investigation and figured I had a bad solonoid valve.

After installation, I noticed a bad smell (burning plastic / electric) that seemed to be coming from the board in the housing next to the air pressure switch.
After looking closely, one of the components looked toasty.

I did tons of searching to try and find this part but no joy.

After getting really frustrated, I finally wondered.. what the heck does this board do anyway?  And do I need it?  after all, the humidostat and air pressure switch are just a series of switches that need to be closed to start water flow.... (right?).

So I omitted the board, and simply put the humidostat and air pressure switch in series and... everything seems to work great.

My question is:
- What function does this board fulfill?
- Why can I not find it anywhere for sale?  (Every offering for an air pressure switch only includes the mechanical air pressure switch, and not this board).
- Am I a fool to run the system in the (simplistic) way I have it set up currently?

(Pic of PCB attached).  Thanks in advance!
--Dave
[image: HoneywellAirPressureSwitchMysteryPcb]

Comment: That is an awful lot going on -- in order to answer the question, we'll probably need much closer-up views of both sides of the board

Comment: Yeah, I realize I didn't give a lot of detail about components on the board or layout.. I was more wondering if some kind of control circuit was common in a setup like this.  From what I can tell, the air pressure switch is usually sold as a "dumb switch", but mine seemed to have this control circuit.  Notably, the model I have brags about low water consumption.  I wonder if this circuit has some timing/interval kind of functionality that reduces the amount of time the valve is open?

Answer (score 1):

The board is the device that inturpets the humidity levels from a sensor and turns on the water solenoid, most units also have a flowswitch to turn the system off if there is no air flow. I would want at least an air flow switch controlling the water valve so the system is not flooding the duct work when no air is flowing , I know it is very small amounts of water but over time it candbuild up. Other than flooding the duct I do not think it will cause a problem to bypass the board.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Does the air pressure switch not perform essentially the same function as a flow switch?  I'm wondering if this board adds some timing function or perhaps switches the solonoid on/off a few times instead of just leaving the solonoid valve open the whole time that air is flowing?

Comment: It should be a combination of pressure/flow and a humidity level sensor you don't want the inside of your home to be a rain forest.